# Why is the coder after using parallelStream not executed?

Tags: java-stream

I intend to execute some time consuming code using using *parallelStream*. This seems to work well but I have the problem that the subsequent code is not executed:

```
@PreDestroy
public void tearDown() {
    final int mapSize = eventStreamProcessorMap.size();
    LOG.info("There are {} subscriptions to be stopped!", mapSize);

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();

    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    eventStreamProcessorMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
        final Subscription sub = entry.getKey();
        final StreamProcessor processor = entry.getValue();

        LOG.info("Attempting to stop subscription {} of {} with id {} at {}", count.incrementAndGet(), mapSize, sub.id(), LocalTime.now().format(formatter));

            LOG.info("Stopping processor...");
            processor.stop();
            LOG.info("Processor stopped.");

            LOG.info("Removing subscription...");
            eventStreamProcessorMap.remove(sub);
            LOG.info("Subscription {} removed.", sub.id());

        LOG.info("Finished stopping processor {} with subscription {} in ParallelStream at {}: ", processor, sub, LocalTime.now().format(formatter));
        LOG.info(String.format("Duration: %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d (hh:mm:ss:SSS)",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(System.currentTimeMillis() - start),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)%60,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - star0)%60,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)%1000));
        LOG.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    });

    LOG.info("Helloooooooooooooo?????");
    LOG.info(String.format("Overall shutdown duration: %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d (hh:mm:ss:SSS)",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(System.currentTimeMillis() - start),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)%60,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)%60,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)%1000));
    LOG.info("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

The code after the parallelStream processing is not executed:

```
LOG.info("Helloooooooooooooo?????");
```

does never appear in the log. Why not?

Comment: is anything *after* that `LOG.info("Helloooooooooooooo?????");` printed?

Comment: Could you please remove all non-essential code (i.e. irrelevant to the problem)? I doubt that I'm the only one who would like to help but are deterred by such a wall of code.

Comment: Nothing from the code above but 
'Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'xxx': java.util.ConcurrentModificationException', whereby xxx is the bean name of the current class

Comment: so wait you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` and you are wondering why that log statement is not printed? do you understand why you are getting that exception?

Comment: I removed some stuff. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I saw that just after asking here...but can't explain yet where this exception comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `eventStreamProcessorMap.remove(sub);` (which you have removed from the code now with the edit that you made).  You are streaming over a `Map` entrySet (`eventStreamProcessorMap`) and removing elements from it - this is not allowed, that is why you get that `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you really want to remove while iterating, use an `Iterator` or `map.entrySet().removeIf(x -> {...})`

Comment: I changed the line: 
eventStreamProcessorMap.remove(sub);
to 
LOG.info(eventStreamProcessorMap.entrySet().removeIf(key -> key.equals(sub)) ? "true" : "false"); 
Now the code behaves as demanded.